# Is header hierarchy website or section scoped?

Tags: html, header, semantics

I would be interested to see some opinions, maybe even some definite answers, the following query:

*What scope determines the level of a header?*

Two extremes I would want to present are the following:

- Website scope
- Section scope

Here are examples for each:

### Website scope

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Haunted fishbowls</h1>

    <div class="article">
      <h2>What does it do to my fish?</h2>
      <p>Fish ipsum</p>
      <h3>Toiletbowl hauntings?</h3>
      <p>Subheader fish ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="article">
      <h2>Stones are sinking upwards</h2>
      <p>Weird stuff is happening in my fish bowl today</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the header levels are determined on a 'global' scope. Even though *What does it do to my fish?* is clearly the first level header for the article, it is a second level header for the website, and thus is marked up as **h2**.

### Section scope

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Haunted fishbowls</h1>

    <div class="article">
      <h1>What does it do to my fish?</h1>
      <p>Fish ipsum</p>
      <h2>Toiletbowl hauntings?</h2>
      <p>Subheader fish ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="article">
      <h1>Stones are sinking upwards</h1>
      <p>Weird stuff is happening in my fish bowl today</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, almost the same HTML has been marked somewhat differently. Notice that inside the article 's, header leveling resets. This is to represents the level of header inside the article. So an **h1** in a **div class="article"** represents the main header of an article, the title. **h1** in **body** represents the main header of the body.

### What would be the way?

So now I ask you, what is the way to go? Is there a clear standard for this? Any answer is very welcome. I am mainly interested in everyone's point of view on this.

Comment: I don't think it matters since the header isn't buried deep within elements. Also putting a header in just a div doesn't say much to seo bots. If you were to put it in an html 5 element like a section, aside, or caption then the bots would know what type of content you are relating it to. Its more about how many h1s you use- which should be one

Answer (score 3):

Both work exactly the same with respect to content outlining ... ***if*** you use the proper sectioning tags (you do not in the second example).  Change `<div class="article">` to `<article>`, and your content will be appropriately sectioned.  `<body>` is also its own sectioning tag, and there is of course `<section>`.

You can see this behavior by plugging your examples into http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/ -- the first example works as you intend (I believe).  The second does not, but if you change `<div>` to `<article>` or `<section>` in the second, it will look like the first one does.

I think that the web is moving more towards favoring the second method instead of picking the proper level of `<h*>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

The generally accepted standard is one `H1` tag per page. Your opening header is used to describe the page. If the page necessitates multiple `H1` tags then you are likely organising your content incorrectly and it should be spread on multiple pages.

Unfortunately the W3C doesn't offer guidelines for this and leaves it to the developer's discretion. However it is not a good practise and definitely not standard behaviour to use multiple `H1` tags. **But why?**

1. Think of this from an accessibility point of view, in your example
   there is nothing that summarises the overall purpose of the webpage,
   the user is forced to view each individual section to ensure they
   understand what this page is about.
2. It is believed that major search engines such as Google may penalise
   your website for overusing the `H1` tag. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=GIn5qJKU8VM)

The W3C does however state:

> There are six levels of headings in HTML with H1 as the most important
>   and H6 as the least.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5

By using multiple `H1` tags you are marking multiple sections of your page as the most important.

To put it in terms of your question. The `H1` should be treated by webpage scope, and you can use lower level headings to denote different sections. Think of heading hierarchy like a tree, the `H1` is the stump and each lower level heading branches off from it. `div` tags do not represent the importance of content and many times a header may be nested deeper than the content it is heading, this does not make it any less relevant - think how your second example would work in such a situation.

Comment: +1: An excellent answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - No, it's a pretty poor answer. It doesn't properly address the question, and instead offers a lot of generic and dubious advice. See Explosion Pills's answer for a far better answer.

Comment: @Alohci Care to explain? I believe it addresses the question and I don't think it is dubious but I am open to constructive criticism.

Comment: @GeorgeReith - The question is about how the semantics of h1-6 elements are affected by container elements. While you say that div elements do not affect this, which is correct, there are elements that do, and their omission makes for a weak answer. On the advice on the use of h1, I'll just point out that multiple use is not the same as "overuse", either to Google or to accessibility users.

Comment: @alohci Indeed, I was assuming the author was referring to a html version < HTML5 as their was nothing HTML5 specific about their question (perhaps this was wrong of me) - you are correct as long as you are using HTML5 correctly, however not everyone is using HTML5 currently. Although I disagree that in the OP's examples multiple `H1` does not constitute "overuse" to an accessibility user as IMO it negatively impacts their browsing experience and serves to confuse them.